# Dynamically assigning namespace annotation by referencing namepace in which a resource is deployed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a yaml file that is deployed in three different namespaces. The namespace is set in context before applying the yaml. Now I want to migrate this to helm chart , and in order to that , I have to first use the vanilla yaml with labels and annotations so that it will look like as if it is deployed by helm  ( I cannot delete the vanilly yaml deployed). So I did the following but it is not working

```
annotations:
     azure.workload.identity/client-id: client_ID
     meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-release-helm
     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: metadata.namespace / POD_NAMESPACE // here it does not work
   labels: 
     azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
```

how can set  meta.helm.sh/release-namespace dyanmically using some sort of built in variable? in my yaml
Note I am not setting namespace explicitly, the pipeline ( which I don't have access) will set the namespace context while deploying the yaml

Answer (score -1):

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/

You need this in your template:

```yaml
     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```